# menu hide and toggle strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(function(){
    $(".OpenTopMenu").click(function (e) {
        $("#top_menu").slideToggle("fast");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function() {
        $("#top_menu").hide();
    });
    $(document).on("touchend", function (event) {
        if (!$(event.target).closest("#top_menu").length) {
            $("#top_menu").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Hi all, i ran into a strange problem with toggle and hide.

As you can see in my code. If i touch the menu button (.OpenTopMenu) the menu (#top_menu) toggle.

And here its the problem. If #top_menu is visible so when i touch on .OpenTopMenu, #top_menu will hide then toggle to visible again. So i can't really hide #top_menu on touching the menu button (.OpenTopMenu).

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use `touchend` and `click` both? `click` would anyway behave nearly like `touchend` on touch devices. Try commenting `$(document).click(function() {...})` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: because i want to test the menu on iPhone and simulator. By removing the click function the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your touchend and click are basically doing the same thing. For mobile uses it's always good to know that a "click" can actually be seen as two events that rapidly follow each other, namely the "mousedown" and "mouseup" event, the last one triggering the "click". On mobile devices, the "click" is triggered at the same time as your "touchend". Now there's also an event called "touchstart" which is triggered when a user put's his / her finger on the glass.

You are right now wondering what all this has to do with your question. Well, it has to do with your document click..

Personally I would solve your problem in the following way;

```
var userClick = function(){
   //you will need something that determines whether your user is 
   //using a mobile device or not.
   return (Browser.isMobile)? "touchend" : "click";
};

var menu = {
   isOnMenu:false,
   isOnMenu_reset:null,
   attachEvents:function(){
      $('#top_menu').on('mouseenter',function(){
          menu.isOnMenu = true;
      }).on('mouseleave',function(){
          menu.isOnMenu = false;
      }).on('touchstart',function(){
          clearTimeout(menu.isOnMenu_reset);
          menu.isOnMenu = true;
      }).on('touchend',function(){
          menu.isOnMenu_reset = setTimeout(function(){
              menu.isOnMenu = false;
          },30);
      });

      $('.OpenTopMenu').on(userClick(),function(){
          $("#top_menu").slideToggle("fast");
      });

      $(document).on(userClick(),function(){
          if(!menu.isOnMenu){
             $('#top_menu').slideToggle("fast");
          }
      });
   },
   init:function(){
       menu.attachEvents();
   }
};
$(function(){
    menu.init();
});
```

Comment: i tried it and the menu hide/show very strange. The menu is shown then hide rapidly

Comment: do you have some html / css, so I can test the behavior for myself ;) that way I can surely solve your problem.

Comment: i wrote a small test with small change on your code by removing userClick and change userClick() to 'click'. You can see the result here : http://jsfiddle.net/9ougpg97/

Comment: I've fixed it, the problem was with the registration of your cursor / touchstart, also fixed the behavior that on clicking on the document, you toggle the menu http://jsfiddle.net/9ougpg97/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `$(document).click()` by somthing like `$(".OpenTopMenu").blur()`. This might not work with old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I only wanted click and touched for testing purpose.

But it only have to work with touchend. This is the working code that i finally use. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".OpenTopMenu").click(function(){
        $("#top_menu").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
$(document).on("touchend", function(event){
    var $trigger = $(".OpenTopMenu");
    if($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length){
        $("#top_menu").slideUp("fast");
    }            
});
```

I tried earlier with

!event.target.hasClass('OpenTopMenu') instead of $trigger !== event.target

in the if condition but it doesn't work. Can someone tell me why the upper code work and this one not?